# netcore - api versioning returns 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, api-versioning

I'm implementing Api Versioning in my NetCore 3 project using package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning` but it's throwing me an error if I try to add version into my router - it works fine if I don't pass the route.

Here is what I have done:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;


namespace Aus.GGG.Company
{
    [Route("v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    public class BaseController : ControllerBase
    {

        [HttpGet("/test.json")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get() => Ok("test");
    }
}
```

That is how I have added my service:

```
        public static IServiceCollection RegisterExtraStuff(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddApiVersioning(config =>
            {
                config.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
                config.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
                config.ReportApiVersions = true;
            });

            return services;
        }

    }
```

And here is the curl that doesn't works:

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:3000/v1.0/test.json
```

And the curl that works:

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:3000/test.json
```

In the last curl, I can see the extra header `api-supported-versions` on response so my configuration looks right, I guess.

Any idea on what is missing?

Comment: Hi @placplacboom, Is my answer helpful to you, if yes, you can mark it as answer thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

You add a slash at the begining in the action route, it will ignore the route attribute on the controller.

If you want the format like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/v1.0/test.json
```

You can change it like below:

```
[Route("v{version:apiVersion}")]
[ApiController]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
public class BaseController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpGet("test.json")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get() => Ok("test");
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, include the name of the controller. For example, `http://localhost:3000/v1.0/base/test.json`

Answer (score 0):

```
[ApiController]
[ApiVersion("1")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/shared/[action]")]
public class DemoController : ControllerBase
{
   public IActionResult TestMethod()
   {
       return ...
   }
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.